# Add migration to set integer to unsigned

Tags: laravel

I've got a table, and I want to add ->unsigned() to the id. At the moment, the migration looks like: `$table->increments('id');`

So I want to do a new migration to set that to unsigned, but there's not much in the documentation to do this. Is this the correct way:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('authors', function($t) {
        $t->unsigned('id', 'authors_id_unsigned');
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::table('authors', function($t) {
            $t->dropUnsigned('authors_id_unsigned');
    });
}
```

I'm just guessing here because I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: I think you can't edit a field this easily. I think you have to delete and recreate (obviously somehow backing up its contents in the process). You may find that if you include the doctrine/dbal package you can do more than without it (like renaming columns) but I still don't think you can affect the type of a column. That said, I haven't tried to do this.

Comment: Ah, ok. That actually makes sense that you can't just change a column like this.

Answer (score 17):

You can modify columns in Laravel 5+, but you have  to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('my_column')->unsigned()->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('my_column')->change();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't change that kind of details with the Schema Builder.

To change it, you have to run a raw query. To achieve this, your migration should look something like this:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('authors', function($t) {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `authors` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST");
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::table('authors', function($t) {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `authors` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST");
    });
}
```